# no puedo visualizar lo datos de mi mongodb con mongoose en node.js

Tags: javascript, nodejs, express, mongoose

```js
//myapp/routes/index.js
//declaramos las dependencias
var express = require('express');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var mongoose = require('mongoose'),
 Schema =mongoose.Schema;
var router = express.Router();
mongoose.connect("mongodb://localhost/Libros",function(err){
 if(err){

 }else{
  console.log('conectado a mongodb');
 }
});

var LibrosSchema =new Schema({
 nombre: String,
 anio: Number,
 autor: String,
 pais: String,
 Region:String,
 descripcion:String,
 foto: String
});

var Libross = mongoose.model('Libros',LibrosSchema);
/* GET home page. */
router.get('/', function(req, res, next) {
 Libross.find(function(err, doc){
  console.log(doc);
  console.log("resivido");
  //res.send(Libros);
 });
  //res.render('index', { title: 'Express' });
  res.send('respond with a resource');
});

module.exports = router;
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: **introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí**]

Answer (score 0):

Estás usando mal la función `find`. Esta función funciona igual que con MongoDB nativo, es decir, **acepta como primer parámetro un objeto** que es el *filtrado* que usará MongoDB para obtener los documentos que coinciden con dicho filtro. Como segundo parámetro, acepta una función en caso se desee usar callbacks. Si no se especifica un callback, entonces `find` devuelverá una promesa.

**Callback**

```
Libross.find({}, (err, libros) => {
  res.render('libros', { libros });
});
```

**Promesa**

```
Libross.find({}).then(libros => res.render('libros', { libros });
```

PD: se escribe *recibido* no *resivido*.